# How to resample and clean a dataframe for a customized calendar and timetable?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

(using Python 3.5.6)

Hi,
am trying to prepare a dataframe for being used with zipline with a customized trading_calendar. Let's say that I imported relevant timeseries data from 2:15am till 21:58pm only business days, that info will be treated by zipline later with frequency="minute"... so data needs to be accurate.

Something like this:

```
de = OrderedDict()
de['DE30'] = pd.read_csv("DE.30.1m.csv",header=None)
de['DE30']['date'] = pd.to_datetime(de['DE30']['time'],utc=True)
de['DE30'].set_index('date', inplace=True)
de['DE30'] = de['DE30'].resample(rule="min").mean()
de['DE30'].rename(columns={2:'open',3:'high',4:'low',5:'close',6:'volume'},inplace=True)

de['DE30'].loc[datetime(2020,3,30,21,57):].head()

          date               open   high    low    close    volume          
2020-03-30 21:57:00+00:00   9846.4  9848.9  9839.4  9843.4  62.0
2020-03-30 21:58:00+00:00   9842.9  9842.9  9840.9  9840.9  2.0
2020-03-30 21:59:00+00:00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-30 22:00:00+00:00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-30 22:01:00+00:00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

The tricky thing here is that: if I resample the full timeseries -like before- then I won't miss any "minute" in my original information (i.e. in case my .CSV does not have some important rows by mistake), however I will have a tedious task to remove all rows between 21:59pm and 2:15am (no trading hours) as well as weekends and holidays info.  How to do this in a 'simple way'..?

If I do not resample it, I will pass to zipline a panel that contains only the correct trading hours and business days (zipline will work with a pre-defined customized trading_calendar that I registered for that) however I can obtain errors like this:

```
KeyError: 'the label [2020-03-31 05:37:00+00:00] is not in the [index]'
```

because the row with the minute 05:37 for that day is not in the original .csv

Option 1) Is it possible to check only if there are 'missing' minutes in an specific timeframe without resampling?  or..

Option 2) in case I decide to resample, is there an easy way to clean rows with undesired times, weekends, etc?